# IDE for phoenix development

Tags: frameworks, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to build a website using phoenix web framework. I saw some IDE's for elixir.Are they support Phoenix development?
What is the best IDE to start with?

Comment: Most people use Sublime Text. There's not a good IDE support for elixir neigther phoenix. Some people are building a plugin for Intelij like these http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7522

Comment: If you consider this question to be asking for specifically Phoenix framework support, then you cant consider it a duplicate of the more general question of editors with Elixir support.

Answer (score 2):

This question will really just lead to a subjective answers, but here you go:

There is currently no elixir specific IDE as far as I know, but rather plugins for various text editors. There is an abundance to choose from: IntelliJ, Atom, Sublime, Spacemacs, Emacs, Vim, whatever you want. Personally I like Atom, but that's just me.